# Moving Phundament web app to production

Tags: docker, yii2, docker-compose, phundament

I'm trying to containerize a Yii2 web app using a fresh installation of Phundament 4.3.0-beta6, Docker 1.11.0 and Docker Compose 1.7.0. The host is an Ubuntu based Linux Mint 17.3.

Everything is working great in *dev* environment, but I don't find the way to correctly build the production image.

I have already used older versions of Phundament and Docker, running in the same issues, so I'm pretty sure I'm not facing a bug: I just misunderstood something.

Problem is, the docker-compose file for local development ([docker-compose.override.yml](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/4.3.0-beta6/docker-compose.override-dist.yml), that overrides [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)) is mounting the root project folder on both *php* and *nginx* containers:

```
volumes:
  - .:/app
```

After some customization I rebuild the php container, the app code is successfully added to the container (as instructed in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/master/Dockerfile)) so I can edit the docker-compose.override.yml file removing the `volume` instruction from the *php* container and everything is OK.

But when I do the same with the *nginx* container and run `docker-compose up -d` *nginx* give me back a 404. That means that it is not finding the landing page into the *php* container. It just finds it when I mount the project folder volume.

I guess that it is not the expected behavior... what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `nginx` needs just the `web` folder of the PHP image for `index.php` and `assets/`.

So you can use `volumes` and `volumes_from`, like so:

```
php:
  volumes:
    - /app/web
nginx:
  volumes_from:
    - php
```

Another option would be to configure `nginx` in a way, that it forwards all requests to the PHP container, but that's not really needed for static files.

**Note!** When you redeploy your application you may need to `kill` and `rm -v` your PHP and nginx containers to apply changes on the volume.

Feel free to create an issue or if you have thoughts about improvements etc...

*Full disclosure: I am a core developer of Phundament.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer and thank you and the rest of *diemeisterei* for *phd*! Ok, so the point of this configuration is to have `nginx` serving directly the static files. What is still not clear to me is if, once in production, I'm supposed to: 1. upload the app/web folder to the server so I can mount the volume or 2. rebuild `phundament/nginx` adding `COPY web /app/web` so it is available from inside the container.

Comment: You're welcome :) When you build *phd* you [`COPY`](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/b28dec88d9fae6f51bedaaa800f2cff9f7f8da86/Dockerfile#L18) the `/app/web` folder onto your `php` image. By declaring it a `volume` you make it also available for other containers (under the same path). Since `nginx` uses `volumes_from` `php` the static files are available there. So no need for building two images, you can use the public `phundament/nginx-one` image.

Comment: Perfect! Now I got it. I need (as you wrote) `volumes: - /app` and not `volumes: -.:/app` so it uses the folder already copied onto the `php` image and not my local folder. Now things are working flawlessly. It was also useful the `-v` flag that you mentioned; I think, until now, I didn't effectively remove former volumes so I got misleading results. Thanks again.